# How to use the new VS 2010 configuration transforms and apply them to other .config files?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, web-config, slowcheetah

I have setup some configuration transforms in my web.config for my connectionStrings, etc.  But I have separated out some areas of my web.config into separate files, ex) appSettings.config.

How can I configure Visual Studio and MSBuild to perform config transformations on these additional config files?

I have already followed the approach of the web.config to relate the files together within my web application project file, but transformations are not automatically applied.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="appSettings.Debug.config">
        <DependentUpon>appSettings.config</DependentUpon>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default the target managing the transformation (`TransformWebConfig`) works only on `web.config` file.

---

To make it work on your `appSettings.config` file you'll have to :

- Set the `Build Action` of your file to `Content`
- Call the MSBuild target `TransformWebConfig` with `ProjectConfigFileName=appSettings.config` and `Configuration=$(Configuration)`.

---

To call MSBuild `TransformWebConfig` target for `appSettings.config` just after the transformation of `web.config` files, you need to add this at the end of your project file :

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <!-- Name of your custom config file -->
  <ConfigFileName>appSettings.config</ConfigFileName>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup>
  <!-- 
      This property is used to handle circular dependency between
      TransformWebConfig and our custom target TransformAppConfig
  -->
  <FirstRun Condition="$(FirstRun) == ''">true</FirstRun>
</PropertyGroup>

<!-- This target will be called one time after a call to TransformWebConfig -->
<Target Name="TransformAppConfig" 
        AfterTargets="TransformWebConfig"
        Condition="$(FirstRun) == 'true'">

  <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)"
           Targets="TransformWebConfig"
           Properties="ProjectConfigFileName=$(ConfigFileName);
                       Configuration=$(Configuration);
                       FirstRun=false"/>
</Target>

<!-- 
    This target will be called one time before PreAutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings 
    to add $(ConfigFileName) to autoparameterization step
-->
<Target Name="AddToAutoParameterizationStep" 
        BeforeTargets="PreAutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings">
  <ItemGroup>
    <_WebConfigsToAutoParmeterizeCS Include="@(FilesForPackagingFromProject)"
                           Condition="('%(FilesForPackagingFromProject.Filename)%(FilesForPackagingFromProject.Extension)'=='$(ConfigFileName)') And !%(FilesForPackagingFromProject.Exclude)">
      <TransformOriginalFile>$(AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStringsLocation)\original\%(DestinationRelativePath)</TransformOriginalFile>
      <TransformOutputFile>$(AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStringsLocation)\transformed\%(DestinationRelativePath)</TransformOutputFile>
      <TransformScope>$(_PackageTempDir)\%(DestinationRelativePath)</TransformScope>
    </_WebConfigsToAutoParmeterizeCS>
    <_WebConfigsToAutoParmeterizeCSOuputFiles Include="@(_WebConfigsToAutoParmeterizeCS->'%(TransformOutputFile)')">
    </_WebConfigsToAutoParmeterizeCSOuputFiles>
  </ItemGroup>   
</Target>
```

Comment: This does seem to work.  My appSettings.config file is transformed, but during my deployment the final config file isn't placed into the output folder.

Comment: I've updated the code to use BeforeTarget and AfterTarget instead of overriding TransformWebConfig dependson targets, and to handle the autoparametization step. Now you custom config file should be in the output folder with web.config

Comment: I've also tried your solution.  Like @Wallace Breza, it appears to work: I can see the transformed EntLib.config file in obj\$(Configuration)\TransformWebConfig\transformed but it isn't deployed. I've tried using the (right-click on project) > Publish... (Publish method: File System) approach and also using Project > Build Deployment Package which I've then run on another machine.  Both leave me with EntLib.config in its original form plus each of the EntLib.($Configuration).config files alongside it.

Answer (score 5):

Something that makes this a lot easier, take a look at the SlowCheetah VS add-in at ... [visualstudiogallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5)

Comment: Thank you Steve !!! I definitely agree with you. A lot easier. I was looking for what you exactly suggested. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code that works for me:

```
    <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Name of your custom config file -->
    <ConfigFileName>ConnectionStrings.config</ConfigFileName>
    <ConfigTransformFileName>ConnectionStrings.$(Configuration).config</ConfigTransformFileName>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- 
      This property is used to handle circular dependency between
      TransformWebConfig and our custom target TransformAppConfig
  -->
    <FirstRun Condition="$(FirstRun) == ''">true</FirstRun>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="AddConfigToTransform" AfterTargets="CollectWebConfigsToTransform">
    <ItemGroup>
      <WebConfigsToTransform Include="@(FilesForPackagingFromProject)" Condition="'%(FilesForPackagingFromProject.Filename)%(FilesForPackagingFromProject.Extension)'=='$(ConfigFileName)'">
        <TransformFile>%(RelativeDir)$(ConfigTransformFileName)</TransformFile>
        <TransformOriginalFile>$(TransformWebConfigIntermediateLocation)\original\%(DestinationRelativePath)</TransformOriginalFile>
        <TransformOutputFile>$(TransformWebConfigIntermediateLocation)\transformed\%(DestinationRelativePath)</TransformOutputFile>
        <TransformScope>$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath($(_PackageTempDir)\%(DestinationRelativePath)))</TransformScope>
      </WebConfigsToTransform>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
  <!-- 
    This target will be called one time before PreAutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings 
    to add $(ConfigFileName) to autoparameterization step
-->
  <Target Name="AddToAutoParameterizationStep" BeforeTargets="PreAutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings">
    <ItemGroup>
      <_WebConfigsToAutoParmeterizeCS Include="@(FilesForPackagingFromProject)" Condition="('%(FilesForPackagingFromProject.Filename)%(FilesForPackagingFromProject.Extension)'=='$(ConfigFileName)') And !%(FilesForPackagingFromProject.Exclude)">
        <TransformOriginalFile>$(AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStringsLocation)\original\%(DestinationRelativePath)</TransformOriginalFile>
        <TransformOutputFile>$(AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStringsLocation)\transformed\%(DestinationRelativePath)</TransformOutputFile>
        <TransformScope>$(_PackageTempDir)\%(DestinationRelativePath)</TransformScope>
      </_WebConfigsToAutoParmeterizeCS>
      <_WebConfigsToAutoParmeterizeCSOuputFiles Include="@(_WebConfigsToAutoParmeterizeCS->'%(TransformOutputFile)')">
      </_WebConfigsToAutoParmeterizeCSOuputFiles>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```