# web.config transform elements not available through System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a web.config file that's transformed using a web.debug.config file. Trying to get access to these values through System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings is yielding nothing.

My web.config appSettings are empty.

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

My web.debug.config transform that's applied. Here's a sample.

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="CommonURL" value="localhost/mysite/" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Here's the code to try and get this value, which returns null.

```
var cu = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CommonURL"];
```

Any idea on why this could be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` is yielding nothing when you run from Visual Studio, then that is the expected behavior. You should add the `CommonURL` appSetting to your `web.config` file and change the entry in the `web.debug.config` to:

```
<add key="CommonURL" value="localhost/mysite/" 
    xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
```

These changes will allow you to get the value specified in the `web.config` when you run from Visual Studio, and will allow that value to be replaced with what is defined in the `web.debug.config` when you execute the transform (for example, through the Publish function or through a custom MSBuild script). Keep in mind that the transforms are applied when you publish, not when you start running a debug or release build. The values that are in the web.config file are always the ones that are honored.

Comment: My initial solution was to have them in the web.config but I assumed that the transform took place each time I ran my project. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Incidentally, if you check my answer to this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422289/how-to-use-visual-studio-2010-config-transform-when-running-debugging-locally/4941639#4941639), there is a way to apply the transforms in Visual Studio using build events, but it's sloppy to say the least. I personally wouldn't use that approach, but it can be done if you're interested.