# Deploying Silverlight Business Application

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I have a silverlight business application which access to a web service. I've created WCF service (in RIA part) which access this web service, and then added Web service reference in SL project. Using this way (proxy), I got service address like this: localhost:7777/... When I deployed application to IIS, this port number was not the same (expected, but...).

Since I couldn't configure this port number, I made separate service (not in the same solution) and deployed to IIS. After that, I added service reference to SL project. Similar like before, but now service is not in the same solution, but independently deployed on IIS. This approach doesn't work. In Fiddler all I could see is HTTP 500.

Could someone please tell me how to deploy SL Business Application which has an access to a WCF service which is deployed separately?

Best,
Joksimovic

Answer (score 0):

What you'll want to do is create separate versions of your ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file (which resides in your Silverlight application and contains the service endpoints for the application).

We create a separate ServiceReferences.ClientConfig for each possible deployment location and then base them on the Silverlight project's build configuration. So, when the project is built and it's build configuration is set to "Debug", we have a ServiceReferences.Debug.ClientConfig whose contents are copied into the project's local ServiceReferences.ClientConfig. Ditto for our Test, UAT, and Release builds.

Here is a link which talks about choosing the correct config based on your build configuration: [How to use Visual Studio 2010 config transform when running/debugging locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422289/how-to-use-visual-studio-2010-config-transform-when-running-debugging-locally)