# Can web.config transforms be chained?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, web-config

Let's pretend that we have the following servers [dev, test, production] and that dev and test are very similar in configuration while production is quite different.

If I'm using web.config transforms that means I have to duplicate a lot of settings för Web.dev.config and Web.test.config. It would be very nice if I could use the same transform mechanism for my transforms so that test.config is based on dev.config.

I have thought of two possible approaches, i'm not sure any of them would work:

- Try to get MSBuild to first transform dev.config and then run test.config against the result when we are running under test configuration
- trying to get the transform mechanism to work for transformations files. I would somehow run test.config against dev.config and create a temporary file which I then use as as a transformation against Web.config.

Does anyone know if something like this is possible? And if so how would one go about to set it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TransformXml` is just an MSBUILD task that is invoked post compile.  If you extend/mod your build you can have it run the transform task twice, or allow the normal run against your configurations, then provide a second file and use the task to perform that.

If you are familiar with msbuild, this is pretty simple.  If not, reply/comment, and I'll try to provide examples later today.

But in the end, yes its possible, as I've had similar need on past projects.

Answer (score 1):

I have even more configurations. And all of them synced with T4. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421157/how-can-i-apply-configuration-transforms-to-entlib-config/5431131#5431131).

Comment: Interesting approach. The ability to include files looks very nice. I think there are a few areas where .config transforms are better though. For example it's possible to go much further when it comes to replacing/removing sections. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I agree with you. T4 based approach is appropriate when you have to change only values in configuration strings or add/remove one or two sections.

Answer (score 1):

Although this has been answered I wanted to update it with an answer reflecting changes made in Visual Studio 2012 that make this considerably easier.

As of Visual Studio 2012 it is possible to "chain" build and publish profile transforms.

As such you can have a "Release" build transform that takes care of common configuration such as switching off debugging, switching on custom errors, and any number of "Publish" transforms which are associated with a publish profile, adding instance specific data such as connection strings and appSettings.

> In VS 2012 (as well as the publishing updates for VS2010 through the
> Azure SDK) now support the concept of publish specific transforms. You
> can also now specify the project configuration used for a profile when
> publishing on the publish dialog...
>
> In this case I have created a profile named Production and set the
> Configuration to Release. When I publish this project the following
> transformations will be applied (if the files exist) in this order.
>
> 1.web.release.config
>
> 2.web.production.config

See [ASP.NET Web Deployment using Visual Studio: Web.config File Transformations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations) for more information.

Comment: Awesome! Will have to look into this

Comment: :( Link is 403 Forbidden

Comment: @Jay13 This answer was written in 2013 and applies to now legacy technology for Microsoft, having been replaced by multiple generations of ASP.NET Core (for which the answer does not apply, although there are similar constructs). A quick web search provides https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations as Microsoft's documentation for the feature.